# dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/libswiftCore.dylib after Xcode Update

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, dylib, dyld

I am having problems with an app I've been working on for a while. Everything was fine until went mad and updated Xcode to 9.4 (previously 9.3).

I'm using a third party framework compiled on swift 4.0.3. I worked perfectly, but after the update it wouldn't compile (can't build the framework compiled on 4.0.3 with 4.1). I downloaded and installed the **Swift 4.0.3 Release Toolchain** and i'm able to build with no errors.

However, when I run the target on the device (iOS 9.0 ipad) it crashes with dyld`dyld_fatal_error:

```
 dyld`dyld_fatal_error:

 0x1fe9008c <+0>: trap  
 0x1fe90090 <+4>: nop
```

The console outputs this:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/libswiftCore.dylib   
Referenced from: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/2E966F50-67E3-4250-858C-382319CD6274/myApp.app/Frameworks/myFramework.framework/myFramework Reason: Incompatible library version: myFramework  requires version
1.0.0 or later, but libswiftCore.dylib provides version 0.0.0
```

Some Facts:

- The Framework is in ***Embedded Binaries*** and ***Linked Frameworks and Libraries*** under General and ***Link Binaries with Libraries*** and ***Embed Frameworks*** under Build Phases.
- This app need's to deploy on iOS 9.0 and the Deployment target is set accordingly.
- I installed Xcode 9.3 again, but I had the same problem using the 4.0.3 toolchain.

My suspicions:

- Can the Toolchain be corrupted in some way? I installed **Swift 4.0.3 Release 2017-12-05 (a)**
- Even though I am working with the 4.0 toolchain, I can only choose from 4.1 and 3.3 under Swift Compiler in Build Settings. I imagine this is overwritten, but not sure.
- My main concern is that even though the deployment target is set to iOS 9.0, under the BASE SDK is set to 11.3, and can't choose another. I can't find the 9.0 SDK on the internet. Could this be the problem?
- Also, all of my certificates are valid and ok.

Thanks in advance, I'll add edits every time I find something new.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I didn't receive any help here, but just in case anyone needs to know, the only way I managed to solve this was asking for an **updated version of the framework** we are using. It appears this is a compatibility problem that has no solution.

Answer (score 0):

Following @Danf instructions solved for me.